# Why doesn't this Pascal's Triangle program work?

Tags: c++, pascals-triangle

Row is user-inputted.

```
cout << "Input the number of rows: ";
cin >> row;
column=row;

int triangle[row][column];

for (i=0;i<=row;i++){
    for (j=0;j<=column;j++){
           triangle[i][j]=0;
    }
}

for (i=0;i<=row;i++){
    for (j=0;j<=i;j++){
           if (j==0 || j==i){
           triangle[i][j]=1;
           } else {
           triangle[i][j]=triangle[i-1][j]+triangle[i-1][j-1];
           }
    }
}

cout << "Pascals triangle with " << row << " rows.";

for (i=0;i<=row;i++){
    for (j=0;j<=i;j++){
        cout << triangle[i][j] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

It does give out proper results when the row is seven,
but it somehow crashes when the inputted row is greater than 8.

Comment: Please show the rest of the code. In particular the declaration of `triangle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely `triangle` is not declared with enough memory for the indices you use. If `row==column==8` then you need to declare it like this:

```
double triangle[9][9];
```

Because C++ uses zero-based indices this allows for indices in the range 0 to 8 inclusive. Most likely your declaration is like this:

```
double triangle[8][8];
```

Comment: Wew. Thanks. I forgot about that one. Sorry, newbie here.

Comment: If the answer is correct you should accept it